# MVC ActionLink in google.maps.InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with JavaScript code

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
                'map': map,
                'title': item.PlaceName
            });

            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png')

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                content: '@Html.ActionLink("Details","Details",new { id= '+item.Id+'})'

            });
```

How to pass `Id` to controller using `@Html.ActionLink`?

In the controller I have a POST version of the Index method. How do I pass the Id using the ActionLink in this method?
In View I try to take ViewBag but nothing is displayed

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

EDIT:
Code of my View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

Id : @ViewBag.id

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?  key=**********" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
.stationInfo {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>

<div id="canvas" style="height: 600px; width:600px;"></div>


@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetMap();
    });

    function GetMap() {

        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

        var Moscow = new google.maps.LatLng(55.752622, 37.617567);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: Moscow,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("canvas"), mapOptions);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.752622, 37.617567);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Name'
        });

        marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png')

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', function (data) {керы
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
                    'map': map,
                    'title': item.PlaceName
                });

                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png')

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                    content:
                        '<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" method="POST">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="id"/>' +
            '<a class="f" href="#" data-id="' + item.Id + '">Details</a></form>'
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })
        });
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "a.f", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var v = $(this).data("id");
                var f = $(this).closest("form");
                f.find("[name='id']").val(v);
                f.submit();
            });
        });

    }       
</script>
}
```

But when I click on the link after the redirect ViewBag is empty(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work that way because your loop executes on the client side and your server code (`Html.ActionLink` call) executes way before that in the server.

What you can do is, Use the Url.Action method to generate the path without the route values and append that with your dynamic variable.

This should work.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: '<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Home")?id=' + item.Id + '">Details</a>'
});
```

Replace `Home` with your controller name where you have the `Details` action method is available.

EDIT : As per the comment

> In the controller I have a POST version of the Index method. How do I
>   pass the Id ?

If you do not prefer to pass the value in the querystring in GET request, but prefer a form post, you can submit a form. Build a form element for each item with a hidden input with name attribute value set to `"Id"` (same as your action method parameter name). You may keep the Id value in html5 data attribute which you will read later.

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" method="POST">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="id"/>' +
            '<a class="f" href="#" data-id="' + item.Id + '">Details</a></form>'
    });
```

Now we need a little javascript to hijack the normal link click behavior. When user clicks the link, we need to read the data attribute value we set (the Id value) and set that as the hidden input field value and submit the form.

```
$(function(){

            $(document).on("click","a.f",function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var v = $(this).data("id");
                        var f = $(this).closest("form");
                        f.find("[name='id']").val(v);
                        f.submit();
             });
});
```

Comment: Could you help with the problem I described in the updated question?

Comment: Your question is confusing ! You want to pass Id value to `Details` action or `Index` action ? If your want to send it to your http post action, you need do a form submit ( hijack the click event on the link and do a form submit in javascript)

Comment: I want to pass Id value to Index action just for a test. Sorry for my mistake. Could you tell us more about this method in the context of my problem?

Comment: But when I click on the link after the redirect ViewBag is empty.
There are any errors in the View (code in question)?

Comment: Viewbag won't be available next request. Use TempData instead of viewbag.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything works as it should, thank you very much again)

Answer (score 2):

you can't pass param from javascript to razor. but you can try to inject the id to the link after he is been generated :

```
var link = '@Html.Action("Details","Details")'+'/'+item.id;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

    content: '<a href="'+link+'">details</a>'

});
```

for the updated questio try to do this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id = id;
    return Index();
}
```

Comment: Could you help with the problem I described in the updated question?

Comment: Thank you for your help)